# Rails can't login to postgresql - PG::Error - password - Correct info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

This is how my database.yml file looks (obviously there are relevant entries for testing and production as well)

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dbname_dev
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: tehpass
```

In terminal I can successfully run the following and log in to the database:

```
psql -U username dbname_dev
```

However after creating this new rails project and running

```
rails g controller ComingSoon index
```

I get the following message when I go to localhost:3000/coming_soon (despite double and triple checking the login credentials)

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Any ideas why I can log in to these databases via "psql" but Rails cannot?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Database.yml:

```
connection: &connection
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: tehpass

development:
  <<: *connection
  database: dbname_development

test:
  <<: *connection
  database: dbname_test

production:
  <<: *connection
  database: dbname_production
```

If this is not working for you then, there might be something wrong during installation.

Visit this [blog](http://blog.willj.net/2011/05/31/setting-up-postgresql-for-ruby-on-rails-development-on-os-x/), hope this might help you out.

---

**EDIT**

---

ERROR CASE:

```
e_sendauth: no password supplied 

fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

This happens under a stock Ubuntu install, and is due to the permissions in pg_hba.conf being too restrictive by default. To allow rails to connect, simply change the bottom of pg_hba.conf to look like this.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

Let me know if this helps or not?

Comment: Yeah I switched to your more DRY method just because. I looked through the blog post and your most recent answer. Concerning the recent answer I'm not sure A) where that file resides and B) if it's even an issue because I'm using Lion

Comment: I guess it must be stored in `/usr/local/var/postgres/`

Comment: is putting your username and password in plain text really a good idea?

Comment: @AndyHayden: You can put username/password in a separate file and then you give the file only read only access. Then you can implement something like this:

`production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: my_db
  username: <%= begin IO.read("/home/my_deploy_user/.db") rescue "" end %>
  password: <%= begin IO.read("/home/my_deploy_user/.db") rescue "" end %>`

Comment: You might also want to checkout bcdatabase gem : https://github.com/NUBIC/bcdatabase

Comment: What are the consequences of this in terms of security?

Comment: In ubuntu 13/10, the file pg_hba is in /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf

Comment: Make sure you restart postgresql via `sudo service postgresql restart` after changing pg_hba.conf. @jdscosta91 I believe the consequences are that anybody that can connect to localhost will have unrestricted access to the database so you should only really be doing this in development.