# Rails: FATAL: Password Authentication Failed For User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having an issue connecting my Postgres database. I created a user for it (it never prompted me for a password), so I ran the command `ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD password` to create one. I set the user and password in my `database.yml` file in my config directory for my Rails project. It's still telling me that I have an authentication failure (like my title) and I have no idea why. I modified my `pg_hba.conf` file from this answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630177/rails-cant-login-to-postgresql-pgerror-password-correct-info). The only thing I can think of that would solve this issue is making my user a superuser. But I'd like to know why this isn't working right now without making it a superuser. Anyone have any idea?

Edit:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "crowdcode" (PG::Error)
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "crowdcode"
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `new'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `connect'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:326:in `initialize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__898392718112352949__prepare__1631078305261036285__callbacks'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/ubuntu/Git/crowdcode/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/Git/crowdcode/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/ubuntu/Git/crowdcode/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/ubuntu/Git/crowdcode/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You are certain you are connecting as the user you think you are? What is the full ERROR message in the db log?

Comment: I just left but I will post the log. Thanks!

Comment: Making your user a superuser won't help. The password is wrong. Check if you have a ".pgpass" file with a bad password.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. make you user superuser: ALTER USER user_name WITH SUPERUSER;
2. edit the file pg_hba.conf : set method from md5 in trust

**TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD**

IPv4 local connections:
host     all     all     127.0.0.1/32    trust

IPv6 local connections:
host     all     all     ::1/128     trust

...............................................................................

Comment: Restart the server just in case: `sudo service postgresql restart`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when working on a Rails application with PostgreSQL database.

The database user already had Super admin rights and permissions to the database that I created, but I was still encountering this error:

```
F, [2020-10-23T08:04:06.031161 #8902] FATAL -- : [4229b10c-e16f-4f26-90cc-facd47b2088c] ActionView::Template::Error (FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "prod_user"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "prod_user"
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that the **Database Password** for the `prod_user` specified for my Database environment variable was not correct in my `.env` file.

I had to modify it to into the correct one.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that a later `host` permissions rule line in the `pg_hba.conf` file had over-ridden the earlier `local` line. I was correctly configuring the `local` line to use md5 authentication but the `host` line was set to `ident` which I changed to `md5`

Note that using `trust` is an insecure method, so you shouldn't use it in any production-style deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was having this error because I was connecting to the wrong port (5432 instead of 5433).